# Adding images and text together on navigation bar on left side

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

// CHANGE COLOR TO BLACK

nav.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

// ADDING IMAGE TO NAVIGATION BAR
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_36.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[nav.navigationBar.topItem setTitleView:imageView];

self.window.rootViewController = nav;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];  

return YES;
}
```

I have tried this code in appdelegate class because i want it throughout the whole project, it works for displaying image, but it shows in centre also i need text which i couldn't display.

Please could someone suggest how can i display both image and text on left side of navigation bar in iOS

Comment: send any one design example

Comment: sorry, i couldn't get your question. can u elaborate please

Comment: add image or screenshot of what you are doing and what you are expecting

Answer (score -1):

Why you are setting imageview to navigation topItem titleview

Replace

```
[nav.navigationBar.topItem setTitleView:imageView];
```

with **nav.navigationbar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem:imageview**

and set  `[nav.navigationBar.topItem setTitle:@"text you want"];

```
UIImage* image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mail-48_24.png"];
CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(0, 0, image3.size.width, image3.size.height);
UIButton *someButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg];
[someButton setBackgroundImage:image3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sendmail)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[someButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];

UIBarButtonItem *mailbutton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=mailbutton;
[someButton release];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it gives me an error as cannot assign string to setTitleView

Comment: its not titleview its just title you can see the updated one.If you accept the answer then accept as correct answer

Comment: No dear, it doesn't show the title yet and just shows the image on center

Comment: is it sliding view controller?

Comment: why can't you try custom bar button with customview as imageview and set as navigationbar.leftbarbuttonitem as that custom barbutton

Comment: Try like the code i have given.. is your controller a slidingview controller or a normal view controller??

Comment: sorry please could you inform what is sliding view, I have tried your code but it doesn't display anything on the navigation bar

Comment: i don't know why moving this discussion to chat failed.. but the way you are setting navigation topview. I use to set like that in slidingview controller where views slide left and right like you know windows slide.. and also the updated code didn't work for you?

Comment: what is ur problem then? can you add in detail including images